# django 1.8 can't override AdminEmailHandler

Tags: python, django, logging, django-settings

i'm on django 1.8 and trying to customize the class
django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler

here is my custom class

```
class MyCustomAdminEmailHandler(AdminEmailHandler):
    # emit copied and overridden from v1.8 so we can add the request .user into the message
    def emit(self, record):
        current_user = None
        try:
            request = record.request
            subject = '%s (%s IP): %s' % (
                record.levelname,
                ('internal' if request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR') in settings.INTERNAL_IPS
                 else 'EXTERNAL'),
                record.getMessage()
            )
            filter = get_exception_reporter_filter(request)
            request_repr = '\n{}'.format(force_text(filter.get_request_repr(request)))
            current_user = request.user
        except Exception:
            subject = '%s: %s' % (
                record.levelname,
                record.getMessage()
            )
            request = None
            request_repr = "unavailable"
        subject = self.format_subject(subject)

        if record.exc_info:
            exc_info = record.exc_info
        else:
            exc_info = (None, record.getMessage(), None)

        message = "User:%s\n\n%s\n\nRequest repr(): %s" % (current_user, self.format(record), request_repr)
        reporter = ExceptionReporter(request, is_email=True, *exc_info)
        html_message = reporter.get_traceback_html() if self.include_html else None
        self.send_mail(subject, message, fail_silently=True, html_message=html_message)
```

And here is the relevant part of my logging config in settings.py

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,    
    'handlers': {
        # can't just override this so customize here
        'mail_admins':{
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'my_utils.logging_utils.MyCustomAdminEmailHandler',
            'include_html': True,
        },

    },
}
```

When i test this out, I don't get HTML email and I don't get my customizations in the email.
Does anyone know what I'm missing?

------ edit ------

@pynchia's comment: django.utils.log already has this relevant logging config for loggers

```
'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
    },
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': False,
    },
    'django.security': {
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': False,
    },
    'py.warnings': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
    },
}
```

----- 2nd edit ------
for the record @pynchia's comment worked. I had to add to manually add it to logging config.
wierd.

Comment: in the settings does your LOGGING dict also include 'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': False,
        }, as part of the 'loggers' key?. If not, it should be included. Read here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/logging/

Comment: i edited my question above. django.utils.log already includes that as default config. do i need to add it again?
if i do, how are emails going out now? i assumed that it is from this very default setting.

Comment: @Pynchia your suggestion worked. i just have no idea where the default logger config comes from now then.